# Why won't this query parse?

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, antlr4

This query runs fine when I submit it through MySQLWorkbench to MySQL 5.7 Community and also MySQL 8 Community.

My grammar is from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/mysql.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    `hr`.`employee`.`FirstName` AS `EmployeeFirstName`
    , `hr`.`employee`.`LastName` AS `EmployeeLastName`
    , `product`.`product`.`Description` AS `ProductDescription`
    , `product`.`unit`.`Unit` AS `Unit`
    , `product`.`product`.`SKU` AS `SKU`
    , `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`Qty` AS `Qty`
    , `product`.`product`.`UnitCost` AS `UnitCost`
    , `product`.`product`.`UnitPrice` AS `UnitPrice`
    , `product`.`manufacturer`.`Manufacturer` AS `Manufacturer`
    , `sales`.`transaction`.`EmployeeNumber` AS `EmployeeNumber`
    , `sales`.`transaction`.`LoyaltyNumber` AS `LoyaltyNumber`
    , `sales`.`transaction`.`StoreNumber` AS `StoreNumber`
    , `store`.`store`.`ZipCode` AS `ZipCode`
    , CAST(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction` AS DATE
    ) AS `DateOfTransaction`
    , CAST(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction` AS TIME
    ) AS `TimeOfTransaction`
    , CAST(
        CAST(
            `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction` AS DATE
        ) AS CHAR CHARSET utf8
    ) AS `DateOfTransactionString`
    , CAST(
        CAST(
            `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction` AS TIME
        ) AS CHAR CHARSET utf8
    ) AS `TimeOfTransactionString`
    , WEEKDAY(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
    ) AS `WeekdayOfTransaction`
    , MONTH(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
    ) AS `MonthOfTransaction`
    , YEAR(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
    ) AS `YearOfTransaction`
    , DAYNAME(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
    ) AS `WeekdayNameOfTransaction`
    , MONTHNAME(
        `sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
    ) AS `MonthNameOfTransaction`
    , `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`TotalPrice` AS `TotalPrice`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (
                            `sales`.`transaction`
                            JOIN `sales`.`transactiondetail`
                                ON (
                                    (
                                        `sales`.`transaction`.`TransactionID` = `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`TransactionID`
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                        JOIN `hr`.`employee`
                            ON (
                                (
                                    `hr`.`employee`.`EmployeeNumber` = `sales`.`transaction`.`EmployeeNumber`
                                )
                            )
                    )
                    JOIN `product`.`product`
                        ON (
                            (
                                `product`.`product`.`SKU` = `sales`.`transactiondetail`.`SKU`
                            )
                        )
                )
                JOIN `product`.`unit`
                    ON (
                        (
                            `product`.`product`.`UnitID` = `product`.`unit`.`UnitID`
                        )
                    )
            )
            JOIN `store`.`store`
                ON (
                    (
                        `store`.`store`.`StoreNumber` = `sales`.`transaction`.`StoreNumber`
                    )
                )
        )
        JOIN `product`.`manufacturer`
            ON (
                (
                    `product`.`product`.`ManufacturerID` = `product`.`manufacturer`.`ManufacturerID`
                )
            )
    )
```

Here's the error thrown by ANTLR4:

> line 1:874 no viable alternative at input 'select
>   `hr`.`employee`.`FirstName` AS
>   `EmployeeFirstName`,`hr`.`employee`.`LastName` AS
>   `EmployeeLastName`,`product`.`product`.`Description` AS
>   `ProductDescription`,`product`.`unit`.`Unit` AS
>   `Unit`,`product`.`product`.`SKU` AS
>   `SKU`,`sales`.`transactiondetail`.`Qty` AS
>   `Qty`,`product`.`product`.`UnitCost` AS
>   `UnitCost`,`product`.`product`.`UnitPrice` AS
>   `UnitPrice`,`product`.`manufacturer`.`Manufacturer` AS
>   `Manufacturer`,`sales`.`transaction`.`EmployeeNumber` AS
>   `EmployeeNumber`,`sales`.`transaction`.`LoyaltyNumber` AS
>   `LoyaltyNumber`,`sales`.`transaction`.`StoreNumber` AS
>   `StoreNumber`,`store`.`store`.`ZipCode` AS
>   `ZipCode`,cast(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction` as date)
>   AS
>   `DateOfTransaction`,cast(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
>   as time) AS
>   `TimeOfTransaction`,cast(cast(`sales`.`transaction`.`DateTimeOfTransaction`
>   as date) as char charset'

Comment: I'm not the greatest MYSQL programmer, but I think your () is causing this.

Comment: Format your query properly.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: You can safely remove all the brackets (inner join is a *commutative* operator)

Comment: You have way too many ( ) that are not needed.

Comment: The point  of the exercise is that ANTLR grammar rejected a query that MySQL Workbench and the MySQL database engine accepted.

Comment: The grammar is bad. It's incomplete and contains errors. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

The query is totally ok. That grammar is broken. Instead use the grammar which comes directly from MySQL/Oracle as part of [MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars). It works with a base class that provides some C++ code to make certain predicates work, but it should be easy for you to update that to other target languages if required.

The linked grammar also allows to use a specific server version to disable/enable certain language parts that changed between versions. It's the most complete grammar you will find and has been directly derived from the original (and latest) [MySQL yacc grammar](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy) (with optimizations for ANTLR4).

Comment: I generated the java versions of the parser and lexer from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars. The first error in the parser is a missing base class called MySQLBaseRecognizer : public class MySQLParser extends MySQLBaseRecognizer {. 

There are also numerous references to an unresolved variable called _ctx.

Comment: That's what I meant. The generated parser derives from that base class which allows it to handle server version and other stuff in a central place. You can either port the C++ code to Java (the code can be found [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/mysql)) or solve the tasks (like handling sql modes etc.) in a different way. You will be rewarded with a parser that works with different MySQL server versions, considers sql modes correctly and implements even the latest 8.0 features.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
CAST ( ... AS CHAR CHARSET utf8 )
```

But according to the grammar you are using, the specification of a character set should be written

```
    CAST ( ... AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 )
```

Apparently, MySQL accepts `CHARSET` as an abbreviation for `CHARACTER SET`, so that grammar is not correct for MySQL.

The production leading to the error is at line 1968:

```
dataType
    : typeName=(
      CHAR | VARCHAR | TINYTEXT | TEXT | MEDIUMTEXT | LONGTEXT
      )
      lengthOneDimension? BINARY?
      (CHARACTER SET charsetName)? (COLLATE collationName)?        #stringDataType
```

Since the provided lexer does recognize the keyword `CHARSET`, you could fix that production by changing `CHARACTER SET` to `(CHARACTER SET | CHARSET)`, but you would probably want to search for other uses of `CHARACTER SET` and change them as well. (For example, in `#collectionDataType` 20 lines further on.) There are about a dozen uses of `CHARACTER SET` in that grammar; some of them accept `CHARSET` as an alias (as in line 1636) but most do not.

Comment: I did write the query by hand using MySQLWorkbench and I arranged it very carefully: https://imgur.com/a/9zgyxhW.  As written, the query runs perfectly when submitted through MySQLWorkbench to the MySQL engine. The parse error did not manifest in the MySQL editor, rather it happened programmatically when the ANTLR-generated code tried to parse the query. Therefore, it doesn't matter how elegantly readable the work might be.

Comment: I tried your fix using MySQLWorkbench (alternate-click on the query in the Schemas window, select Alter Query, replace instances of CHARSET with CHARACTER SET). The MySQLWorkbench editor collapses  CHARACTER SET back to CHARSET when the Apply button is clicked. We are seeing that the grammar I am using conflicts with the grammar used by MySQLWorkbench.

Comment: @nicomp: fair enough. The grammar doesn't correspond to the sql variant you want to use, so you will have to fix the grammar. Making the question readable is still a reasonable request, though.

Comment: Making the grammar readable changes the question.

Comment: @nicomp: As you yourself point out, the readability of the expression has nothing to do with the problem. I wasn't suggesting just changing the question, though: I was suggesting creating a nicely formatted input, feeding it into the grammar, and reproducing it with the corresponding error message. That would indicate the line at which the grammar choked, which would have made it clear that the problem was with `CHAR CHARSET`. (In fact, you can see that from the error message in your question, but it's not nearly as obvious.) ...

Comment: Producing minimal (and readable) test cases is useful both for individual and collaborative debugging. So useful that SO strongly suggests it: see the help section on creating a [mcve].